# iOS changing view properties for different size classes

Tags: ios, size-classes, ios-universal-app

I was wondering if it is possible to change different view attributes for a particular size class.

For example, I have an `ImageView` I chose a size class for iPads, I want to change the background image for that size class only.

I thought that selecting the size class and changing the property applys the changes to that size class only, but that seems to not be the case?

Is there anyway to achieve this with the interface builder? Rather than going into code, and detecting if it is a iPad and applying the changes from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, using size classes you can only change few attributes like font size for `UILabel` etc... if you want to change background image for iPad i suppose only option is by detecting if device is iPad or not.

Answer (score 0):

Only the properties in Interface Builder which have the small '+' button next to them can be customised for different size classes.

However, Asset Catalogs support size class specific images so the OP's specific example of a different background image for some size class(es) is possible without writing code. See the Xcode documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/CustomizingImageSetsforSizeClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH10-SW1

As an aside, you've always been able to specify iPad-specific versions of images by using an `~ipad` suffix in the filename or when using Asset Catalogs. But size classes are more flexible and future-proof because your app might be in a compact size class even though it is on an iPad. For example, each app in a 50:50 split on a landscape iPad is compact width, but on iPad Pro they are regular width.